Movie about a man that cheats on his wife and gets blackmailed
I have had this movie in mind for years but cannot remember the title. Here are the elements that I remember:

There is this guy that meets a young girl.
They hook up one night, he is married.
Her "boyfriend" kicks in the room in the middle of the thing, bunch of things happening that I don't remember.
Time passes by and they both get blackmailed, I think he pays to prevent his wife from finding out.
Many more things happen, but I don't remember what.
He finds out that the girl and his boyfriend actually do this serially, she seduces married men and then they repeat the same scene where he kicks in the room and then there is again and again the blackmailing part.
Somehow he gets some kind of revenge but again, I don't remember.

There should be enough elements to solve the puzzle, maybe?

Welcome to Movies & TV. It has plot details which is nice. However, can you tell us possible release year, language, country or anything at all so that it can help us Identify this movie?

Is there any chance it is "Derailed"?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0398017/
The basic premise is somewhat similar. Jennifer Anniston seduces Clive Owen, they have sex in a motel, and Vincent Cassel is the bad guy who interrupts them, and rob them. Later it turns out that Anniston is Cassel's accomplice.

@AJ no clue! It's a memory from my early youth..

@casspir might very well be. I'll watch it and tell you! Thanks!

OK, please come back with a feedback. Thanks!

@Matteo, when was your "early youth"?

It sounds like the movie Derailed (2005)


Charles Schine (Clive Owen), is an advertising executive. His marriage to Deanna (Melissa George) is deteriorating, and his daughter
  Amy (Addison Timlin) suffers from diabetes, requiring expensive
  medication. Charles's story is being written down by an unidentified
  man in a prison cell.
On a commuter train, Charles encounters an alluring woman named
  Lucinda Harris (Jennifer Aniston). She is a married financial adviser.
  The two show each other photographs of their respective daughters and
  begin to talk. A mutual attraction develops, and the two begin meeting
  frequently. Ultimately, they decide to consummate their affair and
  wind up in a seedy hotel. An armed man—later identified as Philippe
  LaRoche (Vincent Cassel)—bursts into the hotel room, beats Charles,
  and brutally rapes Lucinda. Charles and Lucinda agree not to report
  the crime, as they do not want their spouses to learn of the affair.
  Shortly after, Charles is blackmailed by LaRoche, who threatens to
  kill his family if he does not pay $20,000, which Charles promptly
  pays. A month later, the attacker calls again, this time demanding
  $100,000.
Charles explains his situation to Winston (RZA), an ex-con who works
  as a repairman in his building and whom Charles had earlier
  befriended. Winston offers to scare off LaRoche for ten percent of the
  payout. Charles agrees and embezzles the money from his company. He
  and Winston travel to the meeting location specified by LaRoche,
  intending to get the drop on him. However, before they can act,
  Winston is shot and killed. LaRoche appears and takes the money,
  leaving Charles to dispose of the body. Afterwards, Charles is
  questioned by detective Franklin Church (Giancarlo Esposito) about
  Winston's murder. Later, Charles receives a call from LaRoche who
  claims that he will kill Lucinda if Charles doesn't deliver the
  $100,000. Charles takes the money from an account meant for his
  daughter's medical treatment and makes the payoff.
The next day, Charles stops by Lucinda's company to ask to see her and
  is introduced to the real Lucinda Harris. The woman he met on the
  train is identified as Jane, a temp who had worked there briefly. He
  goes to Lucinda's apartment, which he realizes is actually in the
  process of being rented out. Seeing that Lucinda's photograph of her
  daughter was actually a cut out of a stock picture in a brochure,
  Charles realizes Jane was in on the scam. He tracks her down and sees
  her kissing LaRoche. Determined to retrieve his stolen money, he
  follows Jane's moves and sees that she is seducing another
  unsuspecting businessman (David Morrissey). He rents a room in the
  same hotel where Jane, LaRoche, and their partner Dexter (Xzibit) set
  him up and awaits them as they snare their new target. Jane and the
  businessman go to the room, but Charles knocks LaRoche unconscious
  before he can follow them. Charles breaks in and demands the return of
  his money. A gunfight ensues, and everyone is shot but Charles, who
  watches Jane die. Charles, while in his rented room, is cleared by the
  police near the crime scene. As he leaves the hotel lobby, the
  continued investigation has all contents from the hotel safe laid out
  on the front desk. Charles casually identifies his briefcase, which
  still contains his money, and quietly leaves the hotel.
Charles is later accused by his boss Eliot (Tom Conti) of stealing
  money from the company, and he is arrested for embezzling the $10,000
  that he paid Winston and is sentenced to six months of community
  service, teaching in a prison. During one of his classes, he comes
  across the story about him written on one of the students papers. The
  unknown writer instructs him to go to the laundry room. There, Charles
  finds LaRoche, who survived the gunfight. LaRoche threatens to
  continue to disrupt Charles's life, but Charles reveals that he has
  planned the encounter. He produces a shank, which Winston had given
  him, and stabs LaRoche to death. As Charles leaves, he encounters
  Detective Church who indicates that he knows LaRoche killed Winston.
  While Church suspects Charles of killing LaRoche, he lets him return
  to his family, where Charles reconciles with his wife and daughter.
Wikipedia

Trailer

Watched it, it was that. Thank you so much!
